# How can I calculate Perl logic operations?

Tags: perl, parsing, logical-operators

```
$text = (!a && !b) || (!c && !d)
```

The parser is composed of `()`, `!`, `&&`, `||`. Actually `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` are replaced symbols from a function. I already declared that. After sequence parsing, the actual parsing will be done.

A general parser is for number calculation. But my developing parser is for a sequence of operations.

How can I know the operation sequence?

I have read some Perl code about [recdescent](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=recdescent), but I could not understand that and modified that.

Comment: Who ever voted down, put a comment so that OP know why and might correct it in future.

Comment: I didn't vote it down. My suggestion is make a problem statement at the head of the OP, and then state a specific problem. For example, say something like I tried to do this, but couldn't because of ...

Answer (score 1):

You want [`Math::Symbolic`](http://p3rl.org/Math%3a%3aSymbolic), it is built on [`Parse::RecDescent`](http://p3rl.org/Parse%3a%3aRecDescent) and [`Parse::Yapp`](http://p3rl.org/Parse%3a%3aYapp).